# Comparing/evaluating numbers in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, numbers, compare, pi

I am a  bit stuck trying to find a way to compare the current value of IntPi to the last value of IntPi in my code, our question for our assignment this week was:

**Part 1:  (for 80% of the marks):
USING A WHILE OR A DO-WHILE LOOP write a program to compute PI using the following equation:    PI = 3 + 4/(2*3*4) - 4/(4*5*6) + 4/(6*7*8) - 4/(8*9*10) + ...   Allow the user to specify the number of terms (5 terms are shown) to use in the computation.  Each time around the loop only one extra term should be added to the estimate for PI.**

**Part 2: (for 20% of the marks):
Alter your solution from part one so that the user is allowed to specify the precision required between 1 and 8 digits (i.e. the number of digits which are correct; e.g. to 5 digits PI is 3.14159), rather than the number of terms.  The condition on the loop should be altered so that it continues until the required precision is obtained.  Note that you need only submit this second version of the program (assuming you have it working).**

I've completed the first part, the code is below, although I want to find a way to make the program stop running terms when the current value for IntPi is equal to the last value (which should occur, when IntPi is around 314159265). I don't know how to do this. I know that the while statement should be something like    'while (currentValue != lastValue)', although I don't know how to compare the values within the while loop.

All help will be much appreciated!

I've set some things as statements (i.e the scanner, and output) as they are not necessary to finding the answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComputePI {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*
    System.out.print( "Please enter the amount of  "
            + "digits of PI, you would like to set it too");
    Scanner termScan = new Scanner( System.in );
    int term = termScan.nextInt();
    termScan.close(); 
    */
    double pi = 3.0;
    int loopCount = 2;
    int number = 2;
    int IntPi = 0;

        while ( )
        {               
            if (loopCount % 2 == 0)
            {
                pi = pi + ( 4.0/ ((number)*(number+1)*(number+2)) );
            }
            else if ( loopCount % 2 != 0 )
            {
                pi = pi - ( 4.0 / ((number)*(number+1)*(number+2)));
            }


            IntPi = (int) (pi * 100000000);
            number = number + 2;

            loopCount++;

        } 

        //System.out.print( "The Value of Pi in " +
                //" terms is equal to " + IntPi);
     }

}
```

Comment: why `else if`? You are checking for equal, if that is not the case then it must be not equal. No need to test that again.

Comment: sorry, the second else if is there due to me having tried adding an additional else if to test if the current value for pi was equal to the last value of pi in an earlier version of the code

Answer (score 1):

Just store the old value of `pi` in an additional variable before modifying it :

```
    double pi = 3.0;
    double oldPi = 0.0;
    ...
    while (Math.abs(oldPi-pi)>0.000001)           
    {        
        oldPi = pi;       
        if (loopCount % 2 == 0)
        {
            pi = pi + ( 4.0/ ((number)*(number+1)*(number+2)) );
        }
        else if ( loopCount % 2 != 0 )
        {
            pi = pi - ( 4.0 / ((number)*(number+1)*(number+2)));
        }
        ...
    }
```

EDIT :

I didn't read your question carefully, which resulted in comparing the wrong variables (even though the result is still decent, and the principle is the same for comparing the int variables).

Here's a change that would compare the changes in `IntPi` :

```
      double pi = 3.0;
      int loopCount = 2;
      int number = 2;
      int IntPi = 0;
      int prevIntPi = -1;

      while (IntPi != prevIntPi)
      {               
        if (loopCount % 2 == 0)
        {
          pi = pi + ( 4.0/ ((number)*(number+1)*(number+2)) );
        }
        else if ( loopCount % 2 != 0 )
        {
          pi = pi - ( 4.0 / ((number)*(number+1)*(number+2)));
        }

        prevIntPi = IntPi;
        IntPi = (int) (pi * 100000000);
        number = number + 2;

        loopCount++;
      }
```

Comment: I'd love to know what's wrong with this answer, so that I can fix it (or delete it).

Comment: that makes the inital value for OldPi equal the inital value for pi and the program just outputs nothing... :(

Comment: @GregPenrose Nope. Initially pi == 3.0 and oldPi == 0.0. Then you assign 3.0 to oldPi, but change pi before testing the condition again.

Comment: hmm yeah i see that, but the program just doesnt seem to return an output that way.. see the value for the decimal pi's never equal each other, its only the 9 digit integer that eventually equals the previous, so how would i do this with the integer values, ive done it similar to the way youve shown, but it doesnt work...

Comment: @GregPenrose It should definitely approximate until the resolution of double on the platform gets exhausted.

Comment: No, it doesn't work because `(number)*(number+1)*(number+2)` gives an `int` overflow before the precision limit of `double` is reached.  You really do have an endless loop there.  This answer just doesn't do what the respondent expects it to do.  Also, the question asks for a loop that "... continues until the required precision is obtained ..." and this answer makes no attempt to take the required precision into account.

Comment: @GregPenrose If you change the stop condition to `Math.abs(oldPi-pi)>0.000001`, it stops at 3.141593141775722.

Comment: The latest edit is a definite improvement, but it's still not quite right.  You really need to compare `intPi` (or whatever the multiplied out version is called) with its previous value, because the difference between `oldPi` and `pi` could be very small, but still lead to different values of `intPi`.

Comment: I've removed my downvote anyway, because this is "close enough" to a correct answer.  I'd love to know why this answer got an upvote while it still had the endless loop.  I guess there are people who just upvote without bothering to check how good an answer really is.

Answer (score 0):

```
double pi     = 3.0; 
int loopCount = 2; 
int number    = 2; 
int oldPi     = 0; 
int i         = 0; 
int term      = 8; 

// an integer we use to transfropm double pi 
// to integer pi with the needed precision 

int tt        = (int)Math.pow(10.0,term); 

// compare old PI and new PI in integer space
// based on tt e.g 1000 if term==3

while ( (int)(pi*tt) != oldPi)    {                
    oldPi  = (int) (pi * tt); 
    if (loopCount % 2 == 0)         { 
        pi = pi + ( 4.0/ ((number)*(number+1)*(number+2)) ); 
    } else if ( loopCount % 2 != 0 )    { 
        pi = pi - ( 4.0 / ((number)*(number+1)*(number+2))); 
    } 

    number = number + 2; 

    loopCount++; 
}
```

Comment: youre answer is doing what i want it to do although for some reason its stopping at term one saying (pi*tt) == oldPi when oldPi is 3.166666666 instad of the correct number of precision?

Comment: Which (pi*tt) == oldPi ?

Comment: nevermind, i just realised that i had the line 'oldPi  = (int) (pi * tt);' declared twice, the program is now running, thanks for the help!